# L'Hôpital's rule does not apply?!

Tags: calculus, limits

Apparently, Rogawski's Calculus for AP contains the following problem:

**108. Explain why L'Hôpital's rule does not apply to**

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}}{\sin x} $$

It seems to me that [it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule#Special_case) *does* apply:

The **L'Hôpital's rule** says: **if** $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow c}g(x)=0$ and both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x=c$ and $g'(c)\ne 0$, **then** $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists and is equal to $\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$.
(Note that *nothing* is assumed about differentiability of $f$ and $g$ other than at $x=c$).

1. Define the numerator $f(x)=x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$ to be $f(0)=0$ at $x=0$. Now, both numerator $f$ and denominator $g(x)=\sin(x)$ are continuous at $x=0$ and their values are $f(0)=g(0)=0$.
2. The numerator $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and the derivative is $f'(0)=0$ (the derivative itself is discontinuous at 0, but that is irrelevant - even the existence of the derivative at any point other than 0 does NOT matter). One can see that from the *definition* of the derivative:
   $f'(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{h^2\sin\frac{1}{h}}{h} =
    \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} h\sin\frac{1}{h} = 0$ (see PS step 2 below).
3. The denominator $g$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and the derivative is $g'(0)=\cos 0=1$.
4. Thus the limit is $\frac{0}{1} = 0$.

What am I missing?

PS. Note that I am not asking why the limit is 0. That can be easily seen without L'Hôpital:

1. $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{\sin x} = 1$:
   this is the inverse of the standard limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.
2. $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x  \sin\frac{1}{x} = 0$
   because $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is bounded and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x = 0$,
   this follows from [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).
3. the [Product Rule for Limits](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Proofs_of_Some_Basic_Limit_Rules)
   implies that 
   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}}{\sin x} = 
   \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\sin\frac{1}{x} \times
   \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{\sin x} =
   0 \times 1 = 0$$

PPS Here is the scan from the textbook:

[image]

Comment: It does not apply because of the term $\sin(1/x)$.

Comment: @AlanTuring: why does a "term" prevent a _theorem_ from being applicable? :-) I mean, this is more or less what my daughter's teacher said, but this makes no sense. IOW, what step in my logic is wrong?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534090/the-limit-of-sin1-x-as-x-to-0-does-not-exists

Comment: Note that L'Hospital's rule says that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ if a) $f(x) = g(x) = 0$ and b) **the limit of the quotients of the derivatives exists**. b) isn't fulfilled here.

Comment: You need different approach

Comment: Nope. Since $f'$ isn't continuous at $0$, the existence of $\frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}$ doesn't imply the existence of the limit.

Comment: The special case you linked to says "in the case where $f$ and $g$ are *continuously differentiable* at the point $c$ and where a finite limit is found after the first round of differentiation", but here $f$ is **not** continuously differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: the proof does not use even existence of the derivatives other than at $0$, let along the continuous differentiability assumed.

Comment: @LutzL: the existence of the limit is irrelevant.

Comment: Well, what you wrote that L'Hospital's rule says is true, but it's not what L'Hospital's rule is usually considered to be. Look at the statement on the wikipedia page, that looks quite different. Your rule is much simpler.

Comment: @DanielFischer: alas, you are right about wiki - how would _you_ call the statement I think is called l'Hospital's rule?

Comment: I'd call it an application of Taylor approximation of order $1$.

Comment: As a compromise: As the short proof in wikipedia shows, it is indeed sufficient that $\frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}$ exists in all components. What the task is after is the use of the theorem as given in the book, so one would need its statement from there, that presumably relies on the existence of the limit of the quotient of derivatives. @sds: Is the quote of the theorem from the book?

Comment: @sds This link might be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710786/why-does-lhopitals-rule-fail-in-this-case/1710798#1710798

Comment: @LutzL: the quote is from my memory. the book formulates the rule in Daniel Fisher's form, so, I guess, there is no question anymore. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: Someone posted an answer and then deleted it, and I think it was right - that the textbook used the other form of l'H rule. If you could undelete it, I would accept that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have **misstated** L'Hopital's Rule.  It does not say $\lim_{x\to c}{f(x)\over g(x)}={f'(c)\over g'(c)}$ (with the usual assumptions on $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$).  It says

$$lim_{x\to c}{f(x)\over g(x)}=\lim_{x\to c}{f'(x)\over g'(x)}$$

**provided the latter limit exists**.  In this case

$${f'(x)\over g'(x)}={2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)\over\cos x}$$

for $x\not=0$.  So even though $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}{f(x)-f(0)\over x}=\lim_{x\to0}x\sin(1/x)=0$ (assuming we let $f(0)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$), the hypotheses of L'Hopital's Rule are not fulfilled because $\lim_{x\to0}(f'(x)/g'(x))$ does not exist.  In particular $\cos(1/x)$ has no limit as $x\to0$.

Comment: The problem doesn't even state that $f(0)=0$ though, I think that as written, you can just say $f$ is not defined and therefore notdifferentiable at $0$, and you're done.

Comment: Started to write the same thing, but saw you came to the exact point about the existence.

Comment: @Ovi The function *is* differentiable after being defined $f(0)=0$, so it is not a problem. The very problem is that the limit of $f'/g'$ does not exist.

Comment: @A.G. I completely agree, but I don't see any indication in the problem that they expect us to assume $f(0) = 0$. It just says $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac {x^2 \sin \dfrac 1x}{\sin x}$

Comment: @Ovi The function $x^2\sin(1/x)$ is the very known example of being differentiable at the origin. It is about the same as to have $f(x)=x^2$, $x\ne 0$. There is no question how to define it at $x=0$.

Comment: But $f(x) = x^2\sin (1/x)$ isn't differentiable at $x=0$ because it isn't defined at $x=0$.  The function $h(x) = \begin{cases} x^2\sin(1/x), & x\ne0\\ 0, & x=0\end{cases}$ is differentiable at $x=0$ but it's a different function.  I don't think it's valid to just provide the given function with a specified value at a point outside of its domain, even if it's the "obvious" choice, and especially for something that appears to be at a Calculus I level.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of l'Hopital that the book uses is probably based on the extended mean value theorem,
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{g(x)-g(c)}=\frac{f'(\tilde x)}{g'(\tilde x)}
$$
for some $\tilde x$ between $c$ and $x$. This way of replacing the limit with a limit allows to apply the theorem repeatedly. It ignores that one can also reformulate it as a quotient of difference quotients,
$$
\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{g(x)-g(c)}=\frac{\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}}{\lim_{x\to c}\frac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}
$$
which exists if both functions are differentiable at $x=c$ and $g'(c)\ne0$.

Now when the derivatives are not continuous, one can not conclude about the limit as the book expects. Thus the explored situation is not covered by the assumptions of the used theorem.

---

In general I find it often more instructive to use the mean value theorem (or Taylor expansion) than l'Hopital.

Comment: l'Hopital does _NOT_ require the existence of the derivatives in the neighborhood - just at the limit point.

Comment: Please explain the recent down-voting after I edited to conform to the results of the discussion in the comments to the question.

Comment: I replaced my old downvote with an upvote.

Comment: @sds L'Hopital's rule does require that f'/g' to be definen on a set S=J\{a}, where J is an open interval containing a. Otherwise the limit makes no sense. Limits do not exist at isolated points.

Comment: @Ovi: we rehashed this yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your  $f(x) = x^2 \sin \dfrac 1x$ is not differentiable at $0$, because $f$ is not even defined at $0$. A definition of the derivative is $\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac {f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}$, so as you can see it is required that $f$ be defined at $a$.

Comment: no, $f$ is differentiable everywhere (although the derivative is discontinuous at 0). Moreover, this is the canonical example of such a function.

Comment: @sds Not the way you wrote it. If you define $f(0)$ as $0$ then yes, it is differentiable at $0$. But just $x^2 \sin \dfrac 1x$ is not defined at $0$ so it can't be differentiable there.

Comment: What Ovi said.  It's not ok to just give functions values at points outside their domains, even if those values are the "obvious" choices.  Then they just become different functions..